# Process output data from tflite model in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tensorflow, tflite

I am trying to process the output of the tflite model in swift. The output tensor shape is Shape(rank: 3, dimensions: [1, 25200, 6]). So how can I extract the information out of it which is of return type Data in Swift? This is the code so far

```
func runInference() {
  Task {
    do {
      let interpreter = try Interpreter(modelPath: modelPath)
      try interpreter.allocateTensors()
      do {

        if preprocessedImg != nil {
          try interpreter.copy(preprocessedImg!, toInputAt: 0)
          try interpreter.invoke()
          let outputTensor = try interpreter.output(at: 0)
          let outputData = outputTensor.data
        }

      } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
      }
    } catch let error {
      print("Error: \(error)")
    }
  }
}
```